# Accessing session data in other method in same controller is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, jwt, shopping-cart

I need session to create cart for shopping but after store session in method
when can I use On the same controller but another method can not access session data
I try to add  'StartSession' 'Middleware' on 'Kernel.php' but not working

```
       \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

I use api route and for authentication use tymondesigns/jwt-auth package

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sessions will be persisted after the end of the request life cycle. So if you wanna access the data which you put in the session you need to save the session after setting it by `Session::save();` manually.

Comment: I do it like this but  not work for me